# visual-studio Project settings

Tags: visual-studio

While updating project settings for different sub-projects under a project, i'm updating settings for each sub-project one after the other. Instead of doing so, can i update the common settings once for all the sub-projects?

Comment: Solution : VSPROPS is a visual studio file which can have all the project settings required for whole project. When path to this file is set in the Configuration Properties> General > Inherited Project Property sheets, the common settings are applied to all other property pages. This should be done for debug and release versions for each sub-project.

Answer (score 1):

In the Visual Studio UI, generally the answer is no.

But in most cases you can make a change in a single project then diff the .csproj file (which is just XML) against the previous version to see what the IDE changed (in most cases, only a single element or attribute will change), and then use a global file replace (or similar) to propagate that change quickly through many projects.